# Delete animations on vue-select?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, v-select, vue-select

I need to remove the completely default animation from vue-select.

How to do it? I tried to replace the styles from the box with my own, but I didn’t get the result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is corresponding section in the docs, which states how to change transitions - 
https://vue-select.org/api/props.html#transition

So, you can use it like this:

```
<v-select :options="options" transition="none"></v-select>
```